# Android - capture screen of phone as a movie

Tags: android, screen, capture

for the documentation of a project I would like to record the screen of my Nexus One as a movie or at least in form of a lot of images, which I can convert into a movie. Is that possible? Is there an app for it? For the moment I only know about this screen capture functions in the SDK's tool directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've use two tools and both work well:

1. [Androidscreencast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) fps 4-5
2. [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/2010/01/21/droidscreen/)  fps 30

Comment: thanks !!! Works great !!! AndroidScreencast supports exactly what I need to record a movie.

Comment: On my Android v2.1 (ZTE Racer) I actually get a lot better results with Androidscreencast than I do with Droid@Screen!

Comment: Android 4.4 added a screenrecord utility.  See http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-screen-recording

Answer (score 2):

Do you need it from the device itself, or would from an emulator do?  Here is a [Nexus One Emulation Skin](http://timhoeck.com/2010/01/16/nexus-one-emulator-skin/).

Here is information about the [Dalvik Debug Monitor](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) which claims to:

> which provides port-forwarding services, ***screen capture on the device***, thread and heap information on the device

(emphasis is mine)
I am not an Android Developer, so I can't comment on the usefulness of the tool.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm using multicast and wifi in my application so it's not possible to use the emulator for it. The ddms-tool is the one I meant by pointing to the SDK's tool directory above. Are there any other tools around?

Answer (score 2):

As far I know you can only record screen of an Android device from a PC.

You need to use a tool that will put the phone's screen onto PC.
For this you can use [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/2010/01/21/droidscreen/) . I use this tool for presentation purposes. Than on PC you use whatever screen recording app.

Comment: FFMPEG is your friend, you can take screenshots and then make movie with this library

Answer (score 0):

It is raithe handy to use android 4.x builtin method via adb shell screencap. I wrote a basic PyGtk [adbcap](https://github.com/softkot/adbcap) wrapper to make it even more simple to use.